# How to display the 3D point from text file by using Opengl library

Tags: c++, c, opengl

I would like to plot 3D point specified by the value from column[0] in text file. For example, column[0] equals to 2,then displays 3D point(xyz) following these: (1.529, 0.25,-2.038 ), (1.530,0.253,-2.040), (1.530,0.253,-2.044)

test.txt

> 1 1.529 0.253 -2.038
>
> 1 1.529 0.253 -2.038
>
> 2 1.529 0.253 -2.038
>
> 2 1.530 0.253 -2.040
>
> 2 1.530 0.253 -2.044
>
> 3 1.532 0.254 -2.038
>
> 3 1.533 0.255 -2.036
>
> 3 1.533 0.255 -2.036
>
> 3 1.534 0.255 -2.036
>
> 3 1.534 0.255 -2.036

This is my code

```
#include <Windows.h> 
#include <GL\glew.h> 
#include <GL\freeglut.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <vector> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

char title[] = "Point";

void initGL() {
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); // Set background color to black 
    glClearDepth(1.0f);                   // Set background depth to farthest
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);   // Enable depth testing for z-culling
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);    // Set the type of depth-test
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);   // Enable smooth shading
    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);  
}

void display() {

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // Clear color and depth buffers
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);     // To operate on model-view matrix
    glLoadIdentity();                 // Reset the model-view matrix
    glTranslatef(1.5f, 0.0f, -7.0f);  // Move right and into the screen

    vector<vector<double>> tempdouble;
    ifstream in("test.txt");
    string line;

    double Dstage1x = 0.0;  
    double Dstage1y = 0.0;
    double Dstage1z = 0.0;
    double Dstage2x = 0.0;
    double Dstage2y = 0.0;
    double Dstage2z = 0.0;
    double Dstage3x = 0.0;
    double Dstage3y = 0.0;
    double Dstage3z = 0.0;
    int ii = 0;
    int stage1 = 0;
    int stage2 = 0;
    int stage3 = 0;

    while (std::getline(in, line))
    {
        tempdouble.push_back(vector<double>());
        stringstream ss(line);
        double num;
        while (ss >> num)
        {
            tempdouble.back().push_back(num);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < tempdouble.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < tempdouble[i].size(); j++)
        {

            int st1_x=0; int st1_y=0; int st1_z=0;
            int st2_x=0; int st2_y=0; int st2_z=0;
            int st3_x=0; int st3_y=0; int st3_z=0;

            if(tempdouble[i][0]==1 )
            {

                glPointSize(5);glColor3f(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f); 
                glBegin(GL_POINTS); 


                st1_x += Dstage1x*0;  st1_y += Dstage1y*0; st1_z += Dstage1z*0;   //set value 
                Dstage1x = st1_x + tempdouble[i][1];
                Dstage1y = st1_y + tempdouble[i][2];
                Dstage1z = st1_z + tempdouble[i][3];
                stage1++;
                //cout <<"Check tempdouble[i][0] state1 : " << tempdouble[i][0] <<"\t"<<endl;

                cout << "state1(xyz) : " << "( " << Dstage1x << " ," << Dstage1y << "," << Dstage1z << ")"<< endl;
                glVertex3f(Dstage1x, Dstage1y, Dstage1z);
                //glVertex3f(tempdouble[i][1], tempdouble[i][2], tempdouble[i][3]);
                //glVertex3f(tempdouble[i][j], tempdouble[i][j], tempdouble[i][j]);
                glEnd();
                break;

            }

            if (tempdouble[i][0] == 2) {

                glPointSize(5);glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);  
                glBegin(GL_POINTS); 

                st2_x += Dstage2x * 0;  st2_y += Dstage2y*0; st2_z += Dstage2z*0;   //set value 

                Dstage2x = st2_x + tempdouble[i][1];
                Dstage2y = st2_y + tempdouble[i][2];
                Dstage2z = st2_z + tempdouble[i][3];
                stage2++;
                cout << "state2(xyz) : " << "( " << Dstage2x << " ," << Dstage2y << "," << Dstage2z << ")"<< endl;

                glVertex3f(Dstage2x,Dstage2y,Dstage2z);
                //glVertex3f(tempdouble[i][1], tempdouble[i][2], tempdouble[i][3]);
                //glVertex3f(tempdouble[i][j], tempdouble[i][j], tempdouble[i][j]);
                glEnd();    
                break;
            }

            if (tempdouble[i][0] == 3) {
                glPointSize(5); glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);   
                glBegin(GL_POINTS); 


                st3_x += Dstage3x*0;  st3_y += Dstage3y*0; st3_z += Dstage3z*0;   //set value 

                Dstage3x = st3_x + tempdouble[i][1];
                Dstage3y = st3_y + tempdouble[i][2];
                Dstage3z = st3_z + tempdouble[i][3];
                stage3++;
                cout << "state3(xyz) : " << "( " << Dstage3x << " ," << Dstage3y << "," << Dstage3z << ")"<< endl;

                glVertex3f(Dstage3x,Dstage3y,Dstage3z);
                //glVertex3f(tempdouble[i][0],tempdouble[i][1],tempdouble[i][2]);
                //glVertex3f(tempdouble[i][j], tempdouble[i][j], tempdouble[i][j]);
                glEnd();
                break;
            }

        }

    }
    cout << "stage 1: "<< stage1 << endl;
    cout << "stage 2: "<<stage2 << endl;
    cout << "stage 3: "<<stage3 << endl;
    glutSwapBuffers();  // Swap the front and back frame buffers (double buffering)
}

void reshape(GLsizei width, GLsizei height) {  // GLsizei for non-negative integer
    // Compute aspect ratio of the new window
    if (height == 0) height = 1;                // To prevent divide by 0
    GLfloat aspect = (GLfloat)width / (GLfloat)height;

    // Set the viewport to cover the new window
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    // Set the aspect ratio of the clipping volume to match the viewport
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);  // To operate on the Projection matrix
    glLoadIdentity();             // Reset
    // Enable perspective projection with fovy, aspect, zNear and zFar
    gluPerspective(45.0f, aspect, 0.1f, 100.0f);
}
void changeViewPort(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
}

void render()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    void display();

    glutInit(&argc, argv);            // Initialize GLUT
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE); // Enable double buffered mode
    glutInitWindowSize(640, 480);   // Set the window's initial width & height
    glutInitWindowPosition(50, 50); // Position the window's initial top-left corner
    glutCreateWindow(title);          // Create window with the given title
    glutDisplayFunc(display);       // Register callback handler for window re-paint event
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);       // Register callback handler for window re-size event
    initGL();                       // Our own OpenGL initialization
    glutMainLoop();       

    return 0;
}
```

My problem is that the point shown in the wrong position. It is impossible that column[0](equal to 1,2,3) have all the same points.Can someone help me with this

Answer (score 0):

```
setlocale( LC_NUMERIC, "C");
```

.

Comment: It would be nice if you could improve your answer so that the OP can do anything with it.

Answer (score -2):

https://rocketgit.com/user/bowler17/gl/source/tree/branch/wrench/blob/t.c

line just before big `do while`

Comment: You said that line before big do while. Which line do you mean?